# UIView above an UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uiimagepickercontroller, uialertview

I have an UIAlertView which has an Button.  By pressing that button I need to load a Camera controller(Image Picker)  above the UIAlertView.  Pressing cancel in ImagePicker will go back to UIAlertView of Previous view.

Any Help is Greatly appreciated.  Thanks in Advance.

```
{

    UIButton *aStartTimer = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 170, 45, 45)];
    [aStartTimer setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"timer.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [alertView addSubview:aStartTimer];
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the answer I have posted below

Comment: Before adding this code u should have declared an imagePickerViewcontroller in the name "picker" (which I have used in this code) Then for the alert view u need to add the UIAlertViewDelegate to ur viewcontroller .

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply booleanBoy i did not get an notification for this question. I have actually changed the view as button. Thank you once again for your answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer I will follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        UIAlertView * alertAddImage = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
        [alertAddImage setDelegate:self];
        [alertAddImage setTitle:@"Add Images"];

        [alertAddImage addButtonWithTitle:@"Take a New Picture"];
        [alertAddImage addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
        [alertAddImage setNeedsLayout];
        [alertAddImage show];
        [alertAddImage release];

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex == 0)
    [self imageFromCamera];
}

-(void)imageFromCamera{
 imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
 [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
}
```